# How to serialize into an XmlDocument/XmlElement in order to return it from WCF?

Tags: xml, wcf, xml-serialization, wcf-data-services

What i'm trying to do is return `XmlDocument` from my WCF Service.

The problem is that i got an error "Root element is missing."

here is my code

```
    public XmlElement GetDeviceListXML()// this got [XmlSerializerFormat]and [OperationContract]
    {
        List<Device> list = MyProject.BLL.Device.GetList();// here i getting list of devices from my database
        //Device is object which got [serializable] attribute
        XmlRootAttribute xra = new XmlRootAttribute("Device");
            xra.ElementName = "Devices";
            xra.Namespace = "http://MMEwidencja.pl";
            xra.IsNullable = false;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Device>), xra);
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();;
        try
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, list);
            stream.Position = 0;// that what was I miss 
            xDoc.Load(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return xDoc.DocumentElement;
    }
```

How should I make this work?

**Edited:**
I've got solution for this the problem was that XmlDocument tried to Load stream from last byte to last byte. I've missed to put Position to 0 in that stream.

Comment: You should also remove the try/catch. It does no good, and will show the exception as coming from the wrong location. You should also use a `using` block around your stream, to make sure it gets Disposed.

Comment: By the way, what would happen if you just returned your list instead of serializing it first? Wouldn't WCF serialize it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much cleaner to return the xml as a stream of text and then to load it into a XmlDocument on the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no root element because the XmlDocument.Load function thinks the stream has a 0 byte length.

Maybe read this link : http://geekswithblogs.net/.NETonMyMind/archive/2007/11/15/116862.aspx

Comment: in debbuging mode my memorystream got 2653573 byte lenght so it isn't this

Comment: What I meant is that your load function is at the end of the stream, you need to put your stream to position 0.
Stream.position = 0; should work